# Stopping executing tasks in android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am reading [How to avoid force close error](http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-avoid-force-close-error-in-android/) . here the writer shows that if uncaught exception raises it will redirect to another activity.

My question is, is there any way to `stop all executing task on that activity` and show error as toast and do not go to other activity to show error.

```
so the main problem in the above question is how to stop executing 
task(like asyntask) that are currently running on that activity?
```

Comment: its not about exception handling. its about how to stop all currently running tasks.

Comment: They'll be killed. Author kills current process with all tasks and then android will create new process where error activity will be shown. IMHO it is not a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right, you want to stop all asynctasks as soon as an exception occurs. For this you can write your suspected code in try block and in catch block, check the status of you async task, if it is running ,just stop it. You can check status like this:

```
if(yourAsyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
      yourAsyncTask.cancel(true); // cancel or stop your task.
}
```

Comment: it depends on what you are doing in asynctask. yourTask.cancel(true) usually sends an interrupt signal. You can check this by isCancelled(), if it returns true, just break your loop. Or you can also use custom flags, set them to false when error comes and check them in doInBackground()..

Answer (score 0):

there are several reasons for force close in android

Most causes for Runtime-Exceptions are Nullpointers. Always avoid those problems! That is very necessary.

by using `try catch` block can avoid that problem.

```
try{
    // your code where you are unsure what is the output
}catch(exception e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
 //display the occurred exception as a toast (as you asked in the ques) 
 Toast.makeText(context, "exception : "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Other error-cases - especially in android - are mostly using a wrong or missing context from one to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ..

```
    myTask.stop();
```

Comment: i guess asyntask doesnt have stop method.